# Call XrmSrviceToolKit from AngularJs Factory

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamics-crm, factory, xrmservicetoolkit

I'm developping an angularjs application to integrate it into CRM dashboard, 
i willl use XrmServiceToolKit .
My problem consist in integrating this dependencies in angular Factory i want to use the XrmServiceToolKit web API to extract data and post data to my CRM Organisation 
My Factory service is like bellow:

```
 'use strict';
angular.module('services',[])
    .factory('serviceFactory',['Jquery','json2','XrmServiceToolKit', function(Jquery,json2,XrmServiceToolKit) {
    return{
        getAllCentres: function(){

            return   alert("turnOn service method");
        },

        recupNbrPattes: function(){
            var retour = [];

            return retour;
        }
    }
}]);
```

I have problem is console telling me:

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: JqueryProvider <- Jquery <- serviceFactory
```

My angularController is like this:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap','services']);
app.controller('TestController',['$scope', 'serviceFactory', function ($scope, serviceFactory) {

}
```

What i messed up? Please help.

Comment: Is the service defined in the angular. Check this link for common pitfalls by developers https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr

Answer (score -1):

Try removing 'use strict'        I guess that might cause error